# What is the cleanest way to export one of the view page in D6 to D7?

Tags: 7, views

What is the step by step procedure for exporting a view in d6 to d7?

**Views in D7**

Also I have a content of type 'abc' .When creating a view I 

show -> **content** of type **'abc'**
 
Now for display format i use **fields**
How can I add user uid to the fields.!
I tried adding relationship but could not get through?

[image]

The image I have shown contains the fields in d6 which has user uid even though it has content type 'abc'

Comment: Cleanest way would be re-creating it in D7 :)

Comment: its true.. but I am not able to get the user uid as per the question above?

Comment: Do you mean author or current logged in user?

Comment: not author but User : uid so bascically its logged in user.